# Why Visual Studio Code doesn't show letter "t"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I opened VS Code and realized that it doesn't show the letter 't' in some of my file names. Do you have any idea why?

[image: Tabname]

[image: File Explorer]

Comment: That looks like a render issue, I had the same issue years back and it was one of the reasons I switch away from VSC

Comment: When I click on the file names or the tabs the letter "t" reappears! :)
With no hesitation I have no spaces in file names.

Comment: maybe a font issue? try a different theme.

Comment: after checking numerous themes including the default themes, found out that the Material Themes solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) and [Lars Nielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936269/lars-nielsen). It might be a rendering issue. Thanks to [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2578037/andrew), after trying multiple themes, found out that Material Themes solved the issue.

[image]

[image]